# why does running `which` in a node child process result in different results?

Tags: node.js, terminal

when running the `which` command in terminal (for example, `which yarn`), I get a different result from when I'm running a node script (from the same location) which calls `execSync('which yarn')`

can someone explain why?

tldr;

```
// in terminal
which yarn
// results in 
/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/bin/yarn

// in node
execSync('which yarn')
// results in
/var/folders/0j/xxx/T/yarn--xxx/yarn
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, want to add it as an answer so i can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Node.js process is running as a different user (not as you), and that user has a different path from your account (or at least, it isn't running any `.bashrc` or similar specific to your user account that might add to the path). That makes sense given that your result refers to a folder specific to you (`/Users/xxx/`), but the one from Node.js refers to a central location shared by all users.